# Visual studio profiler takes a long time to load not existing symbols

Tags: visual-studio, profiler

I use Visual Studio profiler to find slow places in my page, and every time after profiling it analyzes report. Via output window and Fiddler I see that it tries to find symbols for ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, iiscore.dll and so on. In Fiddler I see about ~100 attempts to load urls like this:

http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public/iisutil.pdb/FD34931572094C6E9FD7444A2C3600E92/iisutil.pdb
http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public/iisutil.pdb/FD34931572094C6E9FD7444A2C3600E92/iisutil.pd_

Result - 404. Every time.

So, 1 minute I profile my application, then 5 minutes I wait for this. How to fix it to load correct pdbs, or skip load 3rd party pdbs?

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > Symbol file (.pdb) locations

Comment: Any luck? I had to wait 30 min for the symbols to load... Great tool, I wish I could use it.